# Is it possible to select data in mysql matching values from any of the existing columns?

Tags: mysql

Is there a way to select data from any of the existing columns in a databse?

Something like SELECT * FROM mytable WHERE AnyOfTheTableColumns = Something

Comment: If you don't mind spelling out each column.

Comment: Note that this kind of problem can be symptomatic of poor design.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Matching a value to multiple columns (in one statement) from a table using MySQL](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1372860/matching-a-value-to-multiple-columns-in-one-statement-from-a-table-using-mysql)

Answer (score 0):

No, column name can't be variable! You must define your query with explicit definition of columns as;

```
SELECT * FROM mytable
WHERE column1=Something OR column2=Something OR column3=Something
```

Comment: Well, IN() might be a little more elegant.

Comment: yes could be using reverse IN notation like: SELECT * FROM mytable WHERE Something IN (column1,column2,column3)